# How to access new properties or ini file in php without passing its absolute path?

Tags: php, windows, apache, ini, properties-file

How to access new properties or ini file in php without passing its absolute path?? I mean where should i place the properties or ini file (One imp thing It should not be in same folder as my php file).?? 
Imp Info: Apache server has been used in windows operating system.

Comment: what did you mean with *new properties or ini file*? additional php.ini file? htaccess file? php constant or var-file? xml-file? ...

Comment: Thanks for you comment. additional php.ini file.

Comment: And also it can be any file which you have mentioned above, the thing which i need to achieve is, i should be able to read the contents of file(ini,htaccess, etc) from php file without its absoulte path. @donald123